# General formula for multiplying a matrix by a power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

> $$M = \begin{pmatrix}2&2\\ -4&8\end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Find formulas for the entries of $M^n$, where $n$ is a positive integer.

So I think this problem involves multiplying a matrix by itself continuously. But I do not think I have observed a link between the older entries and the newer entries each time I have multiplied this matrix by itself. It just seems to be random changes in the numbers (unless I am doing something wrong). Am I supposed to create a sequence out of each of the entries and then derive a general formula?

Any assistance would be highly appreciated!

Comment: **Hint:** If a matrix is [diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) then it can be written in the form $M=SDS^{-1}$ with $D$ a diagonal matrix at which point $M^n = (SDS^{-1})(SDS^{-1})\cdots(SDS^{-1})=SD^nS^{-1}$.

Comment: As a special case of that, if a $2\times2$ matrix has distinct real eigenvalues, then it can be decomposed into a linear combination $\lambda_1 P_1+\lambda_2 P_2$ of projections with the property that $P_1P_2=P_2P_1=0$. You can do this without having to find any eigenvectors.

Comment: Anyway, in order to give you a reasonable answer to this question, you need to provide more context: what are you meant to have learned about matrices so far?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* By Cayley–Hamilton, $A^2=10A-24I$. Then $A^n = a_n A + b_n I$ with $a_{n+2}=10a_{n+1}-24a_n$ and $b_{n+2}=10b_{n+1}-24b_n$. Then, both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are given by linear combinations of $4^n$ and $6^n$. The coefficients are found by considering $a_0, a_1, b_0, b_1$.

Comment: To be honest, this is probably more work than simply finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors and diagonalizing the matrix.